# How to turn a tuple of key value pairs into a tuple of values in typescript

Tags: typescript, tuples

I want to create a tuple from the values of a key-value pair tuple

```
type PairsTuple = [{ k: 1 }, { k: 2 }, { k: 3 }]

type ValuesTuple = ValuesFromPairs<PairsTuple>
// [1, 2, 3]
```

how would I implement `ValuesFromPairs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
type ValuesFromPairs<T extends {k: number}[]> = { 
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { k: number } ? T[K]["k"] : never 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noStrictGenericChecks=true&esModuleInterop=false&experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=6&jsx=0&module=1&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&noImplicitOverride=true&ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4GcAqBXMAbaBeKAbQG8oBrALigEYoBfAGilMqgCZ6mWqBmegXQCwAKBGhIUAGpxsGCCgBiSAPYBbeMhQAeNFAgAPYBAB2AExTNWxjKoBGEJHUL8AfFAKkRUIgGkoCY3IIEGUAMyg0fio0Qh9%20PUMTc2ZyKms7B3ooAH4I2P5CACIyQvi0iAA3TJE6ETFwaGlZeUwcfCkZOUUVdURULQ1UVtwXEQB6MaJqJjYmHn4gA)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general solution:

```
const pairsTuple = [{ k: 1 }, { k: 2 }, { k: 3 }];

type InferValue<T extends Record<any, unknown>> = T extends Record<any, infer I> ? I : never;

type ValuesFromPairs<T extends Record<any, unknown>[]> = { [K in keyof T]: InferValue<T[K]> };

const returnTuple = <T extends Record<any, unknown>[]>(arr: T) => {
    return arr.map((obj) => Object.values(obj)[0]) as ValuesFromPairs<T>;
};

const tuple = returnTuple(pairsTuple);

console.log(tuple);
```

Only issue is that the type of `tuple` is `number[]` instead of `[number, number, number]`. Same issue with the solution you accepted.